# Access 2010 Me.Refresh/Me.Requery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form that I want refreshed when the submit button is clicked. Preferably those that have default values will be restored and those without will be blank.

The submit button has an attached OnClick Macro that, checks to make sure all fields are filled, if so an action query runs that inserts a new row into a table.

So its after this action query that I want the refresh to occur. I have tried researching and come across suggestions that suggest using VBA code Me.Requery or Me.Refresh. I'm not 100% on how to incorporate this into the macro. The RunCode command doesn't recognize the function I put the code in, and The convert macro to VBA option in the top left is grey'd out.

I'm new to Access and just not seeing where the communications are for code and macros if someone could please elaborate for me I would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider my solution as a brief introduction to VBA.  If you care to learn the language, you will find there is very little you cannot do.

Within your submit button properties, there should be an 'Event' tab.  In this tab, the On Click should be set to [Event Procedure].  Click the three dot button just to the right of that, and it will launch the VBA editor.

All you need to have here between the Private Sub and End Sub lines are these lines of code:

```
DoCmd.RunMacro ("Mac_1")
Me.TextBox1.Value = "Null"
Me.CombBox1.Value = "Null"
Me.Refresh

MsgBox "Your Save Was Successful.", vbOKOnly, "Saved"
```

"Mac_1" is the name of the macro you want to execute.  the ME.Refresh executes as soon as mac_1 finishes, and will refresh the page.  Be sure to enclose it in a proper quote (") and not a double tick ('').

Comment: Thank you for the response. I inputted your code and the macro still runs, but refresh as well as trying requery didn't change anything.

Comment: @User1480899, this will have the same effect as the macro I suggested which is why this doesn't work. I thought we established in the comments to my answer that what you wanted was to clear the INPUT values from your form. Have you tried my updated suggestion?

Comment: Ben, you are correct that this won't work exactly the way User1480899 wishes, a more complex solution would need to be developed.  I did only offer this answer as an introduction to VBA and show programatically how your solution could be coded.

To get the values entered in the combo boxes and text fields, each control would have to be individually set after the macro is invoked, and after those fields have been set to default values, then a refresh can be performed.
example:

    me.textbox1.value = "NULL"
    me.combobox1.value = "NULL"

Comment: I have updated my code example to demonstrate setting a text box or a combo box to a "NULL" value, but you can use anything you wish.  Also, you have code to display an informational message box informing the user that the save was successful, although it has no real way of knowing if the save was actually successful.  There should be some logical operation that can present two boxes, one if the save succeeds, and another if there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

The Requery command can be used from both within `VBA` code or a macro. It sounds like you are using the macro designer so you can use the `Requery` macro action instead of `VBA`.

Just add this to your macro after you have inserted your new data.

[image]

This macro action lets you specify a control to requery. The parameter can be left blank to requery the source of the active object. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177360%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

**Edit**

In response to your comments, I think you should try experimenting with the `SetProperty` macro action (more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177424%28v=office.12%29.aspx)).

[image]

I have attached this macro to a button click event and the value from the TextBox called *txtInputValue* is cleared. The Value field is left blank as you want to fully remove the value from the text box.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or some more details of your macro?

Comment: So the Macro looks as such:<br/>                           
                                                                     
If ( fields are null )<br/>
   Msg Box [Error]<br/>
Else<br/>
   Run Query MarkDown<br/>
                                                                     
The Query goes like this:<br/>

INSERT INTO DownPeriod ( EquipmentID, DownDate, DownTime, Comments )
SELECT EquipmentID, Forms!Down!DownDateBox, Forms!Down!DownTimeBox, Forms!Down!CommentsDropDown
FROM Equipment
WHERE Title = Forms!Down!EquipmentDropDown;

Comment: Where did you place the Requery action? Also, have you verified that the macro is being called and the data is being updated? I.E. is there actually anything new to show when the UI is refreshed? Also, you should really edit your original post to include the extra information so that it can be formatted and is easier to read.

Comment: Sorry for the disgusting post:  And I removed the Requery after it didn't work it was placed directly after the OpenQuery.  <br/>
Yes, the data is updating perfectly. All I want the refresh to do is clear all data they entered to give a visual acknowledgment that the data was imputed.

Comment: Are you trying to show the NEW data or remove the OLD values from the form that have just been inserted? Requery refreshes the datasource and shows the NEW values.

Comment: i would like to have the inputted data removed, I suppose I could just close and reopen the form but I feel like there should be a better way.